# Run a jar file from a specified folder in jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, executable-jar

I have an application developed using java , and the runnable jar is created which is working from the command line.
To run the jar file , normally I used to open a command line from the folder where jar is placed. And to run the jar file, if the jar is placed in D:/ drive, then **D:/>java -jar abc.jar** will run the application

**Now I want to run this jar file in a system , through jenkins pipeline**.

The pipeline job is created. I want to know

1. How pipeline can access a specified folder?
2. Open a cmd.exe from that specified folder
3. Run the jar file from that location

**Expected result**

*From Jenkins pipeline job -> Access and run a jar file kept in a specified folder*

Or is there any other way of doing it to get the expected result?

Thank you for the support!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dir` to access the folder with the path where your `jar` file is available.

```
// dir("<Your path where scripts are present>")
dir ("D://"){
 // Execute your java file
 bat "java -jar abc.jar"
 }
```